# I want to Install storage cloud package. during installation show error how to solve this nodemon app.js run successfully ]

Tags: mongodb, backend, npm-install, web-development-server

I want to install **NPM storage cloudy package**. But the package are not installed show error.
And when I run a nodemon app.js then app are crashed.
[nodemon app.js error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrsWy.png)
 [npm install multer-storage-cloudinary package install error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuqEY.png)

I am expected to package are successfully install then nodemon app.js run smoothly. Without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Download and authenticate gcloud. Alternatively, use Cloud Shell , which comes with gcloud already installed.
Set your project ID. Every command requires a project ID. Set a default project ID so you do not need to provide it every time.